# How to make first root element to open by default in tree component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using tree component i,e (Tree with partially loaded data).Here is the 
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kdepalderex?file=app%2Ftree-loadmore-example.html) link. I want child element of the first root element to be opened by default. something like this[image] How to do this? I am not getting any useful resources.

Comment: use [matTreeNodeToggleRecursive] option of mat-tree
 <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [matTreeNodeToggleRecursive]="true">
            <mat-icon>
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
          </button> {{node.Name}}

Comment: Its not working,I think i placed the code in wrong section.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it Here:
[To open the first tree-node by default in tree component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997301/to-open-the-first-tree-node-by-default-in-tree-component)

[This is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9d7cvk)