# To open the first tree-node by default in tree component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using tree compone i,e (Tree with partially loaded data).Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kdepalderex?file=app%2Ftree-loadmore-example.html) example

I want first  rootLevelNode to be openend by default.
Something like this

[image]

I am unable to get any related documents.How can i do it?

I got this suggestion,still it doesn't work.

use 
 `[matTreeNodeToggleRecursive]` option of mat-tree

```
 <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle 
  [matTreeNodeToggleRecursive]="true"> 
  <mat-icon> 
    {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
  </mat-icon> 
 </button> {{node.Name}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

As It can be toggled by only `click`

Reference ----> [Toggle](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview#toggle)

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9d7cvk)

TS:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.getElementById('node-Vegetables').click();
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button id="node-{{node.item}}" mat-icon-button [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" (click)="loadChildren(node)"
         matTreeNodeToggle>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
 </button> {{node.item}}
```

Comment: Let me try your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The last answer not work with me; when data return from API that solutions work fine with me

```
openFirstTreeNode() { this.treeControl.expand(this.dataSource.data[0]) }
```

and call function `ngOnInit()`.